# How to use different optimizers for layers in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, optimization

I have some three Dense layers. I would like to look at an example where different optimizers are used for these three layers (for example, RMSProp, Adadelta, Adam).
Something like this:

```py
tf.keras.layers.Dense(250, ..., optimizer='rmsprop')
tf.keras.layers.Dense(250, ..., optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adadelta(learning_rate=1))
tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,  ..., optimizer='adam')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```py
import tensorflow_addons as tfa

# ...

optimizers = [
    tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),
    tf.keras.optimizers.Adadelta(learning_rate=5),
    tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
]

optimizers_and_layers = [(optimizers[0], model.layers[0]),
                         (optimizers[1], model.layers[1]),
                         (optimizers[2], model.layers[2])]

optimizer = tfa.optimizers.MultiOptimizer(optimizers_and_layers)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, ...)
```

For saving — `save_weights_only=True`:

```py
checkpoint_path_best = "best.h5"
modelcheckpoint_best = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_path_best, monitor='val_accuracy', save_best_only=True, mode='max', save_weights_only=True)
model.fit(train_data, train_labels, ..., callbacks=[modelcheckpoint_best])
```

and for loading:

```py
model.load_weights('best.h5')
```